# phonegap iphone: exit application code if no Internet connection found

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am using phonegap to develop one of my iPhone app. In the index.html page I am implementing a small javascript code just to check if the Internet is available or not inside the `onBodyLoad()` function as below:

```
function onBodyLoad() {                                       
    if (!navigator.onLine) {   
         alert('offline');     
    }

    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    //alert("here!");   
}
```

This just work fine but I want to exit from the application when user taps the "Ok" button of that alert message.

I tried the add `navigator.device.exitApp()` after the alert but did not work.

How can I exit from the application after tapping the "OK" button from the alert message?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`navigator.device.exitApp()` is not supported on iOS as Apple is pretty down on apps closing themselves.

It *is* possible I believe by setting the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` boolean to YES in your applications info plist (in a PhoneGap application this is in Supporting Files -> -info.plist).

See:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Specifically: "Opting out of Background Execution"

Answer (score 4):

Your app will (probably) be rejected by Apple if you try to exit it from within.

See that thread

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/5e34e6d2e6b8b8e6/72fb6c05566fac58